Open Vim help in vertical split
There seems to be a few posts about this, e.g.: Opening Vim help in a vertical split window.
The following works for me - opening help docs in vertical split at left - placed in ~/vimfiles/ftplugin/help.vim as suggested in above post:
au BufEnter */doc/*  wincmd L | wincmd H
However, it appears to me (and my perhaps naïve eye) that the */doc/* part is unnecessary and unhelpful, as it picks up files outside Vim help doc system.
However all other suggestions only work for the first help doc opened but other, different help docs open in horizontal split above? For example, this:
autocmd BufEnter <buffer> wincmd L | wincmd H
To reiterate, with this in ftplugin/help.vim the first help doc opens in vert split to left; subsequent different help docs open in horizontal split above.
Found an answer but still have questions
[vim 9.1 (2024 Jan 02) MS-Windows 32-bit GUI version with OLE support]
Whether in vimfiles/ftplugin/help.vim or vimfiles/after/ftplugin/help.vim these do not work (see above for details of how it doesn't work):
if !exists("helpCmds_loaded")
        autocmd!
        au BufEnter <buffer> wincmd L | wincmd H
    let helpCmds_loaded = 1
endif

The above doesn't work and no syntax highlighting of help file
if !exists("helpCmds_loaded")
        au BufEnter <buffer> wincmd L | wincmd H
    let helpCmds_loaded = 1
endif

The above doesn't work but do have syntax highlighting of help file
However, if I have just this, it works:
au BufEnter <buffer> wincmd L | wincmd H

Was there something wrong with the way I was using conditional if !exists(...) and autocmd?

I see now that is was the use of a global variable in conditional. I should use a buffer-local variable instead.

I notice that my solution is very close to the solution you tested unsuccessfully on your configuration. Could you tell us which version of Vim you are using (:version)? Could try to reproduce the problem with a very minimal .vimrc file (e.g.: filtype plugin on)

I'm a bit confused. The start of your text is stating that au BufEnter <buffer> wincmd L | wincmd H is only working for the first help buffer but the second part is stating that it works fine in all the situation. Maybe some precision could help me to figure out.

Sorry, I introduced new issue I thought maybe was relevant about syntax highlighting of help doc. Basically if I wrap autocmd in conditional it does not work whether in after/ftplugin or ftplugin. Without conditional, it works. When I say, does not work, I mean it works once; then if help doc closed, further different help docs open in horizontal split.

Do you still have something open in your question ? How can we help you further ? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solutions using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

What works for me is to have a help.vim file in ~/after/ftplugin with the following content:
autocmd BufEnter <buffer> wincmd L

What is does is to associate to every help buffer (i.e.: buffer of filetype=help) the wincmd L command that moves the buffer at the extreme left of the screen.
Remark:
~/vimfile/ftplugin/help.vim:
if !exists("helpCmds_loaded")
  au BufEnter <buffer> wincmd L | wincmd H
  let helpCmds_loaded = 1
endif

set the trigger only to the first help buffer since helCmds_loaded is a global variable and not a buffer variable.

Oh, ok. So autocmd is associated with the first help doc opened. And is not sourced for further help docs because of the global variable. I should use b:helpCmds_loaded, yes? Thinking about it, the conditional seems redundant.

Just want to ask, autocmd BufEnter <buffer> wincmd L opens "at the extreme left of the screen"? For me it opens to the far right and wincmd L | wincmd H opens to extreme left.

@Tom see :help CTRL-W_L: yes, L is right, H is left. And I think you do want b:helpCmds_loaded; you don't want to create the autocommand on the buffer more than once. I generally use augroups for that.

FWIW I have the following since long time (OBS! Vim9 script):
augroup vimrc_help
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufEnter *.txt if &buftype == 'help' | wincmd H | endif
augroup END


An alternative solution could be:
command! -nargs=? Help vertical help <args>

function! CorrectHelpCall()
  if getcmdtype() != ':'
    return "\<CR>"
  endif

  let l:command = matchstr(getcmdline(), '^h\%[elp]\>')
  if empty(l:command)
    return "\<CR>"
  endif

  let l:cmdline = getcmdline()
  return "\<End>\<C-u>Help" . l:cmdline[len(l:command):] . "\<CR>"
endfunction
cnoremap <expr> <CR> CorrectHelpCall()

In this solution an Help command is introduced that creates the help window vertically.
The Enter in command mode is catched and if the commands called is the help command it is replaced by its Help counter part.

I would write vertical rather than vert here. Also (less important if you want to keep your version) empty(l:command).

Thanks for the feedback :-) I have adapted the answer.
